# Mesos master not elected as leader

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos

I am deploying Mesos/Marathon/zookeeper  on a cluster of one physical machine : is this a viable configuration ?
(I have two machines, but begin by the first one)

When launching Mesos I get the following result on the page : "No master is currently leading, This master is not a leader ..."

I put the quorum at 1, is it a possible value ? I tried 0 but mesos doesn't even start.

EDIT

## cat mesos-master.INFO

```
Log file created at: 2015/10/19 15:58:15
Running on machine: 192.168.0.38
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I1019 15:58:15.592771     8 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I1019 15:58:15.593093     8 main.cpp:229] Build: 2015-10-12 20:57:28 by root
I1019 15:58:15.593111     8 main.cpp:231] Version: 0.25.0
I1019 15:58:15.593123     8 main.cpp:234] Git tag: 0.25.0
I1019 15:58:15.593135     8 main.cpp:238] Git SHA: 2dd7f7ee115fe00b8e098b0a10762a4fa8f4600f
I1019 15:58:15.593276     8 main.cpp:252] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I1019 15:58:15.660604     8 leveldb.cpp:176] Opened db in 67.183194ms
I1019 15:58:15.678915     8 leveldb.cpp:183] Compacted db in 18.242065ms
I1019 15:58:15.678962     8 leveldb.cpp:198] Created db iterator in 14924ns
I1019 15:58:15.678982     8 leveldb.cpp:204] Seeked to beginning of db in 1323ns
I1019 15:58:15.678998     8 leveldb.cpp:273] Iterated through 0 keys in the db in 2556ns
I1019 15:58:15.679056     8 replica.cpp:744] Replica recovered with log positions 0 -> 0 with 1 holes and 0 unlearned
I1019 15:58:15.680054    30 log.cpp:238] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
I1019 15:58:15.680531    36 recover.cpp:449] Starting replica recovery
I1019 15:58:15.680735    36 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in EMPTY status
I1019 15:58:15.683269     8 main.cpp:465] Starting Mesos master
I1019 15:58:15.684293    35 replica.cpp:641] Replica in EMPTY status received a broadcasted recover request
I1019 15:58:15.684648    37 recover.cpp:195] Received a recover response from a replica in EMPTY status
I1019 15:58:15.685711    31 recover.cpp:566] Updating replica status to STARTING
I1019 15:58:15.688724    31 master.cpp:376] Master 74ee40e5-16b6-4a40-8288-4f563806b5cb (192.168.0.38) started on 192.168.0.38:5050
I1019 15:58:15.688765    31 master.cpp:378] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --cluster="" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname="192.168.0.38" --hostname_lookup="true" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --ip="192.168.0.38" --log_auto_initialize="true" --log_dir="/etc/mesos/logs" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --quorum="1" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_store_timeout="5secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_reregister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos" --zk="zk://192.168.0.38:2181/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I1019 15:58:15.689028    31 master.cpp:425] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I1019 15:58:15.689049    31 master.cpp:430] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I1019 15:58:15.689071    31 master.cpp:467] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W1019 15:58:15.689100    31 authenticator.cpp:505] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I1019 15:58:15.689422    31 authenticator.cpp:512] Initializing server SASL
I1019 15:58:15.695821    31 contender.cpp:149] Joining the ZK group
I1019 15:58:15.699548    34 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(2)@192.168.0.38:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.706737    30 master.cpp:1542] Successfully attached file '/etc/mesos/logs/mesos-master.INFO'
I1019 15:58:15.706755    34 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I1019 15:58:15.706826    34 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.710538    35 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 24.699241ms
I1019 15:58:15.710598    35 replica.cpp:323] Persisted replica status to STARTING
I1019 15:58:15.710695    37 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in STARTING status
I1019 15:58:15.710979    32 replica.cpp:641] Replica in STARTING status received a broadcasted recover request
I1019 15:58:15.711148    31 recover.cpp:195] Received a recover response from a replica in STARTING status
I1019 15:58:15.711293    37 recover.cpp:566] Updating replica status to VOTING
I1019 15:58:15.723206    37 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(1)@192.168.0.38:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.730281    37 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I1019 15:58:15.730325    37 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos/log_replicas' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.731256    33 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(4)@192.168.0.38:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.731343    33 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I1019 15:58:15.731359    33 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.731947    30 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(3)@192.168.0.38:5050) connected to ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.733675    30 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (1, 0, 0)
I1019 15:58:15.734716    30 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.734612    31 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 23.245997ms
I1019 15:58:15.734902    31 replica.cpp:323] Persisted replica status to VOTING
I1019 15:58:15.734987    32 recover.cpp:580] Successfully joined the Paxos group
I1019 15:58:15.735080    32 recover.cpp:464] Recover process terminated
I1019 15:58:15.745573    33 network.hpp:415] ZooKeeper group memberships changed
I1019 15:58:15.745687    32 group.cpp:674] Trying to get '/mesos/log_replicas/0000000030' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.749068    35 network.hpp:463] ZooKeeper group PIDs: { log-replica(1)@192.168.0.38:5050 }
I1019 15:58:15.750468    36 contender.cpp:265] New candidate (id='30') has entered the contest for leadership
I1019 15:58:15.751054    33 detector.cpp:156] Detected a new leader: (id='30')
I1019 15:58:15.751231    34 group.cpp:674] Trying to get '/mesos/json.info_0000000030' in ZooKeeper
I1019 15:58:15.751909    33 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@192.168.0.38:5050) is detected
I1019 15:58:15.752105    34 master.cpp:1603] The newly elected leader is master@192.168.0.38:5050 with id 74ee40e5-16b6-4a40-8288-4f563806b5cb
I1019 15:58:15.752182    34 master.cpp:1616] Elected as the leading master!
I1019 15:58:15.752208    34 master.cpp:1376] Recovering from registrar
I1019 15:58:15.752290    33 registrar.cpp:309] Recovering registrar
I1019 15:58:15.752581    35 log.cpp:661] Attempting to start the writer
I1019 15:58:15.753067    34 replica.cpp:477] Replica received implicit promise request with proposal 1
I1019 15:58:15.774773    34 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 21.627305ms
I1019 15:58:15.774910    34 replica.cpp:345] Persisted promised to 1
I1019 15:58:15.775125    34 coordinator.cpp:231] Coordinator attemping to fill missing position
I1019 15:58:15.775501    33 replica.cpp:378] Replica received explicit promise request for position 0 with proposal 2
I1019 15:58:15.790747    33 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (8 bytes) to leveldb took 15.185008ms
I1019 15:58:15.790833    33 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 0
I1019 15:58:15.791260    33 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 0
I1019 15:58:15.791342    33 leveldb.cpp:438] Reading position from leveldb took 23444ns
I1019 15:58:15.803988    33 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (14 bytes) to leveldb took 12.606014ms
I1019 15:58:15.804051    33 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 0
I1019 15:58:15.804256    32 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 0
I1019 15:58:15.815990    32 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (16 bytes) to leveldb took 11.675285ms
I1019 15:58:15.816064    32 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 0
I1019 15:58:15.816087    32 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned NOP action at position 0
I1019 15:58:15.816222    34 log.cpp:677] Writer started with ending position 0
I1019 15:58:15.816537    32 leveldb.cpp:438] Reading position from leveldb took 9246ns
I1019 15:58:15.817867    36 registrar.cpp:342] Successfully fetched the registry (0B) in 65.515008ms
I1019 15:58:15.817951    36 registrar.cpp:441] Applied 1 operations in 11601ns; attempting to update the 'registry'
I1019 15:58:15.819144    30 log.cpp:685] Attempting to append 173 bytes to the log
I1019 15:58:15.819236    32 coordinator.cpp:341] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND action at position 1
I1019 15:58:15.819448    30 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 1
I1019 15:58:15.832018    30 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (192 bytes) to leveldb took 12.520293ms
I1019 15:58:15.832092    30 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 1
I1019 15:58:15.832268    35 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 1
I1019 15:58:15.844065    35 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (194 bytes) to leveldb took 11.769077ms
I1019 15:58:15.844130    35 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 1
I1019 15:58:15.844175    35 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned APPEND action at position 1
I1019 15:58:15.844462    31 registrar.cpp:486] Successfully updated the 'registry' in 26.468864ms
I1019 15:58:15.844506    30 log.cpp:704] Attempting to truncate the log to 1
I1019 15:58:15.844571    31 registrar.cpp:372] Successfully recovered registrar
I1019 15:58:15.844599    30 coordinator.cpp:341] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE action at position 2
I1019 15:58:15.844714    31 master.cpp:1413] Recovered 0 slaves from the Registry (134B) ; allowing 10mins for slaves to re-register
I1019 15:58:15.844790    37 replica.cpp:511] Replica received write request for position 2
I1019 15:58:15.858352    37 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (16 bytes) to leveldb took 13.469108ms
I1019 15:58:15.858502    37 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 2
I1019 15:58:15.858723    37 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 2
I1019 15:58:15.874608    37 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 15.810315ms
I1019 15:58:15.874725    37 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~1 keys from leveldb took 27159ns
I1019 15:58:15.874747    37 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 2
I1019 15:58:15.874764    37 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 2
I1019 15:58:19.851761    37 master.cpp:2179] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-45acfb6e-2a61-46e8-bef3-7bc5d0e76567@192.168.0.38:33773
I1019 15:58:19.851974    37 master.cpp:2250] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I1019 15:58:19.852358    30 hierarchical.hpp:515] Added framework a927b696-0597-4762-9969-f1fe2a5d7a2e-0000
I1019 15:58:34.856995    34 master.cpp:4640] Performing implicit task state reconciliation for framework a927b696-0597-4762-9969-f1fe2a5d7a2e-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-45acfb6e-2a61-46e8-bef3-7bc5d0e76567@192.168.0.38:33773
```

**w3m http://192.168.0.38:5050**

```
    [loading]
Toggle navigation Mesos

  • Frameworks
  • Slaves
  • Offers

  • {{state.cluster}}

No master is currently leading ...
× This master is not the leader, redirecting in {{redirect / 1000}} seconds ... go now

{{ alert.title }}

{{ alert.message }}

  • {{ bullet }}
```

Comment: The quorum should be at least more or equal to half the zookeeper servers you have

Comment: ok, so I have 1 zookeeper server, the quorum should then be >= 0.5

Comment: as quorum can not be float, I put 1.

Comment: CAn you check the mesos serever logs, to see if it's running and connecting to the zookeeper. Please, show them all in your post

Comment: Check if you followed this configurations: https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/datacenter/install/

Comment: where should I see the mesos server log ? Which is the env variable setting this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92741/discussion-between-luis-alves-and-romain-jouin).